# PayPal subscription button with custom parameter

Tags: paypal

can someone please advise me on how to create a Paypal subscription button that is associated with my subscription plan and can contain a custom parameter?

I would like to specify a custom parameter in the button for each buyer such as CustomerId=1234 so, I can register the buyer as my member immediately.

I currently found the way to create a subscription button but cannot add any parameter.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating the subscription, add the parameter `custom_id`.

This is documented in the [Create subscription request body](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body).